# Code segment in Python keeps changing Dataframe content despite not being referenced

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following Dataframe in Python, where "data" = the full dataset composed of 2 columns of strings, 'Description' and 'Category'.

"dataTrain" is a subset of "data"

"catBag" is a list of all the words used in the 'Description' from rows of a specific 'Category'

"catDict" is a list of all the words used in the 'Description' from rows of all the other Categories.

"catUnique" returns me all the words that are unique to a specific category.

The nested loop replaces the 'Description' text with only words that are unique to the row's category.

```
classNames = sorted(list(set(dataTrain['Category'])))
catUnique = [[] for _ in range(len(classNames))]
dataTemp = dataTrain
for i in range(len(classNames)):
    catBag = set() 
    data2 = dataTrain.loc[data['Category'] == classNames[i]]
    data2['Description'].str.lower().str.split().apply(catBag.update)

    catDict = set()
    data3 = dataTrain.loc[data['Category'] != classNames[i]]
    data3['Description'].str.lower().str.split().apply(catDict.update)

    catUnique[i] = list(catBag-catDict)
    for j in range(len(data2)):
        if len(catUnique[i]) > 0:
            data22 = data2
            dataTemp.at[data22.index[j], 'Description'] = " ".join(list(set(data22.at[data22.index[j], 'Description'].lower().split()) & set(catUnique[i])))
```

However, running this code updates dataTrain's Description text despite not being referenced. Even when I change it so that dataTrain isn't used as an input, it still gets updated.

This issue means that more words are missing from "data3" as non-unique words are stripped from previously processed Categories.

I think it's to do with the data2['Description'].str.lower().str.spl...... lines but not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last line, you are updating dataTemp, which is the same as dataTrain.

In order to make a copy of dataTrain, use

```
dataTemp = dataTrain.copy()
```

In Python, `dataTemp = dataTrain` only creates a new variable that references the same object.